# Filter rows by color and apply formulas to visible rows only

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried searching for this but have only ended up with a non-functioning Frankenstein sub routine. I need to:

-Filter Column B to Grey Cells.

-In column AB on all visible rows, set formula equal to the values in Column B.
    If a row is filtered out, I need it to remain blank.

Bonus question (because I'm a pain in the neck): I need to do some kind of loop to replicate this process in columns AC:BA as well. For example, filter Column C to grey cells, and make all visible cells in AC equal to the corresponding row in Column C.

EDIT: I was also thinking to just do a Control + Find, replace any cell where the background color is no fill, and replace with a blank or 0. I can't get that to work either, however.

Code that I have (currently I'm stuck at having selected the first visible cell in Column AB):

```
Dim Last_Cell As Range
    Set Last_Cell = Range("A3").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)

  ' [Good ]Filter Column B by Color
    Range("$A$3", Last_Cell).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=RGB(165,165,_ 
165), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

    ' [Pending ] Set all visible AB cells = same row in B
    Range("AB3").Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Do Until Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    If Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    End If
    Loop
```

Comment: Use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to drop a value in a visible cell

Comment: Also, do not worry about the loop yet. You need to take steps to the final goal. If this doesn't work on one column, why bother with the column loop? Just focus on a one column solution, then look into extending the solution to other columns via a loop

Comment: When I tried that, it cleared the contents of the first visible cell in AB. There were only two rows- are more required for that to work? Thank you!

Comment: Note that your loop will exit at the first instance of Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True, so even if it did something, it would do it just once.

Comment: That is not VB.NET code.  If the question has nothing to do with .NET, you may remove the tag

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code for you to tinker with.

The sub below takes 4 arguments: the whole filter column, the whole formula column, the row number of the filter headers, and the RGB color to look for.

```
'ASSUMPTION: prngFilterCol is to the left of prngFormulaCol.
Public Sub FilterByColorThenSetFormulas(ByVal prngFilterCol As Excel.Range, ByVal prngFormulaCol As Excel.Range, ByVal plHeaderRow As Long, ByVal plColorRGB As Long)
    Dim rngFirstCellInFilterArea As Excel.Range
    Dim rngLastCellInFilterArea As Excel.Range
    Dim rngFilterTarget As Excel.Range
    Dim rngFormulasTarget As Excel.Range
    Dim rngVisibleCells As Excel.Range
    Dim lColumnsDifference As Long

    'Initialization.
    Set rngFirstCellInFilterArea = prngFilterCol.Cells(plHeaderRow, 1)
    Set rngLastCellInFilterArea = Application.Intersect(rngFirstCellInFilterArea.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).EntireRow, prngFormulaCol)
    lColumnsDifference = prngFilterCol.Column - prngFormulaCol.Column

    'Remove existing filtering.
    prngFilterCol.Worksheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    If rngLastCellInFilterArea.Row > plHeaderRow Then
        Set rngFilterTarget = prngFilterCol.Worksheet.Range(rngFirstCellInFilterArea, rngLastCellInFilterArea)

        'Clear the contents (formulas) in the target column.
        'Our assumption (above) is crucial.
        Set rngFormulasTarget = rngFilterTarget.Columns(rngFilterTarget.Columns.Count)
        rngFormulasTarget.ClearContents

        'Filter.
        rngFilterTarget.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=plColorRGB, Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

        'Find the remaining visible cells.
        'Note: SpecialCells will fail if there are no visible cells, hence the On Error Resume Next.
        Set rngVisibleCells = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngVisibleCells = rngFilterTarget.Offset(1).Resize(rngFilterTarget.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not rngVisibleCells Is Nothing Then
            'Assign formulas to the visible cells within prngFormulaCol, using the relative notation of FormulaR1C1.
            rngFormulasTarget.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[0]C[" & CStr(lColumnsDifference) & "]"
        End If
    End If

    'Cleanup.
    prngFilterCol.Worksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    Set rngFormulasTarget = Nothing
    Set rngVisibleCells = Nothing
    Set rngFilterTarget = Nothing
    Set rngLastCellInFilterArea = Nothing
    Set rngFirstCellInFilterArea = Nothing
End Sub
```

You can invoke it as follows:

```
Public Sub TestFilterByColorThenSetFormulas()
    Dim lColIndex As Long

    'Example 1.
    'Column 2 is B, column 28 is AB.
    FilterByColorThenSetFormulas Sheet1.Columns(2), Sheet1.Columns(28), 3, RGB(165, 165, 165)

    'Example 2.
    'Loop from column B to Z, putting formulas in columns AB to AZ.
    For lColIndex = 2 To 26
        FilterByColorThenSetFormulas Sheet1.Columns(lColIndex), Sheet1.Columns(lColIndex + 26), 3, RGB(165, 165, 165)
    Next
End Sub
```

I trust you will find your way around the code. Try it out, put some breakpoints, see how it works, and have fun.

Note that the code leaves the target worksheet unfiltered. If you'd like filters to stay, you can re-establish them afterwards, programmatically. I'll leave this as an exercise ;-)

Below is my test worksheet's setup:
[image]